# I am trying to make a linkedQueue data structure program for my a class

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, queue

I feel like I am close to finishing, but am not entirely sure. I am getting an error with my `deQueue` method where I am trying to point to (*head) and equal to `nodeString`. The error is `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. This program is in C language.

This program eventually is supposed to be a stress test and I must run it 1,000,000 times where I just queue and then dequeue a 100,000 character string each time the program runs. I may not be doing it right, but I think my algorithm is pretty close. I mostly just want to figure out why I am getting the error with the pointers. I am not very proficient in using them as we just learned them in class.

I even added a solution to part of the problem where I declared `char * nodeString = NULL;` and I didn't before have the `*` there. Still though it doesn't like it when I use `->`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <limits.h>


char nodeValue;//intitial filling of the queue
char nodeString;//for the main running of the program: enqueue and dequeue 1000000 times
int charCount = 0;//counts the amount of chars in the strings that fill the nodes.
int nodeCount = 0;//keeps track of the amount of nodes
int runCount = 0;//keeps track of amount of times ran

struct Node{
    char data;
    struct Node *next;
};

void enQueue(char * string, struct Node ** head, struct Node ** tail){
    struct Node* newNode;
    newNode = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if(*head == NULL){
        newNode = *head;
        newNode = *tail;
    }//if the queue is empty
    newNode->data = (*string);//newNode obtains the data of the passed string
    newNode->next = (*tail);//the next node is set to NULL


};

void * deQueue(struct Node **head, struct Node **tail){
    char * nodeString = NULL;
    struct Node* tempNode;
    tempNode = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    *nodeString = (*head)->data;
    nodeString = (*head);//value is set to the data of the head node
    tempNode = *head;//tempNode is set to the head node
    *head = (*head)->next;

    free(tempNode);
    //return &nodeString;
    return 0;
};

////creates a 100000 character string for the node
char * createString(){
    char *str = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
    while(charCount <= 10){
        char rand = 'A' + (random() % 26);
        str[charCount] = rand;
        charCount++;
    }//while charCount < 15
    return str;
};

int main(){
    //makes the node
    struct Node ** nodeH;
    struct Node ** nodeT;
    nodeH = (struct Node**) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    nodeT = (struct Node**) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    while(nodeCount < 10){
        char *nodeString = createString();
        //nodeValue = ;//creating a string with the createString function
        enQueue(nodeString, nodeH, nodeT);//passing to enQueue
        nodeCount++;//increment nodeCount

    }//while nodeCount < 10
    while(runCount <= 50){
        if(nodeCount <= 10){

            char *nodeString = createString();//creating a new string to enQueue everytime I deQueue
            deQueue(nodeH, nodeT);//deQueue
            nodeCount--;//substract nodeCount when deQueue
            enQueue(nodeString, nodeH, nodeT);//enQueue
            nodeCount++;//add nodeCount when enQueue

        }//if
        runCount++;
    }//while runCount <= 1000000
}//main
```

Comment: Your `createString()` is broken. You allocate 10 bytes, but first time you write 11 characters and no terminator, so with corrupt memory anything could happen. Please study [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `char * nodeString = NULL;
...
    *nodeString = (*head)->data;` :  `*nodeString = ..` is `NULL` dereferenced.

Comment: Ok thanks, but now the same error is popping up in my enQueue where newNode->data = *string....